# Download all chat history programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-openai

I am looking for a way to access the full chat history of interactions with Azure OpenAI.

I can't find a way to do this programmatically. When asking Bing Chat enterprise it goes completely wrong and eventually starts hallucinating giving me endpoints that do not seem to exist.

Can you share any pointers / documentation on how to download all chat history programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no chat history because the models within the service is stateless. Instead, customers/partners would build stateful applications that preserve chat history on top of the Azure OpenAI platform.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/concepts/use-your-data

You can log content of conversation variable to a local file.

Comment: In addition to Ram's response, there are a few interesting repo about logging and monitoring: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/openai-python-enterprise-logging